# Breeze - constructor not being invoked

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I'm building a new Ng 1 project using Breeze. I need to add client-side properties to some entities. I added a constructor, but it does not get called. I added a post initializer, it is not called either.

```
// a convention can self-register as the default
breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();

// create a manager to execute queries
service.manager = new breeze.EntityManager("/api/pts");

// access to the manager's store to add custom client-side properties ..
service.metastore = service.manager.metadataStore;

// entities with client-side properties ..
service.metastore.registerEntityTypeCtor('PtsWine__Pts_BreezeModel', PtsWine, ptsWineInitializer);

var PtsWine = function () {
    debugger;
    this.uiDayUid = 0;
}

var ptsWineInitializer = function (pw) {
    debugger;
    pw.uiDayUid = 0;
}

var query = new service.EntityQuery().from("Wines");
return service.manager.executeQuery(query)
    .then(function (d) {
        debugger;
        /// ???  examining d.results shows 40 PtsWine__Pts_BreezeModel entities but 
        ///      constructor and initializer above were never invoked .. ???
    })
    .fail(function (response) {
        toastr.error("Server Error: failed to retrieve listing.")
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The initialization sequence does not seem correct to me. At the time registerEntityTypeCtor is executed PtsWine and ptsWineInitializer are undefined. Remember javascript hoisting concept? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

You need to define the variable before calling registerEntityTypeCtor.

Comment: duhh .. that's the fix.  Thx Filipe I've been so staring at it that I didn't see this most obvious js gotcha .. and yes I had also forgotten "use strict" so double duhh on me.  thx again!